# Search and Replace Certain Extensions in Hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, hyperlink

I have an excel file with a load of hyperlinks. Some of the hyperlinks match a certain pattern, lets say `file:///\\location\file_name_<xxx>.pdf`, where `<xxx>` varies. There are also other hyperlinks that are similar, say `file:///\\location\other_file_<xxx>.pdf`.

I want to be able to search and replace all hyperlinks matching (using simple * wildcard for explanation) `*file_name*.pdf` and replace with `*file_name*.mht`.

So any hyperlink to a PDF matching `file_name_<xxx>` replace its extension with `mht`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions by using Visual Basic under the developer tab. You have to do quite a bit of coding. I would offer my own explanantion, but the answer to this question has been explained pretty thoroughly in another stackoverflow question. Click here >> ([How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops))

In Summary:

**Step 1:** Add VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

**Step 2:** Define your pattern

**Step 3:** Run as macro, Run as an in-cell function, or Loop Through Range

I believe the example that would be the most help for you would be **Example 4:**

```
Private Sub splitUpRegexPattern()
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")

For Each C In Myrange
    strPattern = "(^[0-9]{3})([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{4})"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = C.Value
        strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
            C.Offset(0, 2) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
            C.Offset(0, 3) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$3")
        Else
            C.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks to this and the link I have solved my problem. Many thanks

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!